# "ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil" getting this error even after updating dateutil folder in site-packages folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-dateutil

I am new to Python. Can someone suggest me how to handle the error `"ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil"`. I have gone thru similar questions but I have followed steps mentioned over there and downloaded folder and updated it in site-packages folder where matplotlib folder is also there.

But still I am getting this error. Can someone suggest me a solution for this. Thanks in advance for support.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

This is the exact error I am getting.

Comment: Can you `import dateutil` on its own?

Comment: What is your system? linux? Windows? have you try to find dateutil ?

Comment: dateutil is probably not in your python path.  How did you install mpl?

Comment: I tried using import dateutil then I am getting dateutil is not available in python path

Comment: Its windows and yes I have dateutil in site package folder along with matplotlib

Comment: I have installed mpl matplotlib-1.3.1.win32-py3.2

Answer (score 5):

For some reason, uninstalling and reinstalling python-dateutil fixes this issue.

```
pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil
```